# How to detect if Tomcat http connection timedout

Tags: java, http, tomcat

Would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this for me.
Below is my scenario:

- http request comes in to tomcat server
- some method in application service layer is invoked
- the service layer takes a long time while processing this request
- during this time the remote-http-client runs out of 'http-read-timeout' clock on its side and drops the connection.

I assume Tomcat will drop the underlying connection automatically. (please correct me if I am wrong). Is there anyway for the server side service-layer to detect that the underlying connection is no longer active. I would like the service-thread to stop some unnecessary processing in such a case.

Comment: How much processing are we talking about here?

Comment: Thanks for the link Tim. Looks like no way to detect this. Maximum time is about 20sec. I am carrying out some xml processing using jaxb and it's taking a long time when I receive around 1k requests at the same time (I think some lock contention is taking place while initing jaxb context). I am trying to improve the xml-processing part too. Cant really go async way for this particular request due to some internal issues. Thanks once again.

Comment: No, there _is_  a way to detect it but you must write something to the response.

Comment: Ahh. the problem in my case is that I am using a jsonrpc lib which hosts this endpoint and just makes calls to my service-layer when the request arrives. so in the service-class I dont have a direct reference to the response stream. Will need to figure out a way to get that.